Class library dll throwing exception Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0 but it reference version 5.2.0
Class Library using Visual Studio 2022 community v 17.9.6 TragetFramework 8 project file
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>.0
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <AssemblyName>AchieveResource</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>Achieve.AchieveResource</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Achieve.Common">
      <HintPath>..\Achieve.Common\bin\Debug\net8.0\Achieve.Common.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="AchieveResource1.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>AchieveResource1.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

   </Project>

A console application is referencing this dll and when one of the static methods is called, it throw and error
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5'. The system cannot find the file specified.
System.TypeInitializationException
  HResult=0x80131534
  Message=The type initializer for 'Achieve.AchieveReserouce.ConnectionStrings' threw an exception.
  Source=AchieveResource
  StackTrace:
   at Achieve.AchieveReserouce.ConnectionStrings.GetEnterpriseConnectionString()
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Dev\Achieve\2022Projects\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 4

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5'. The system cannot find the file specified.

The line in the console application is
OUConstr = Achieve.AchieveReserouce.ConnectionStrings.GetConnectionSringForOU(1004);

I tried before referencing System.Data.SQLClient 4.8.6 and I was getting a similar error
Inner Exception 1:
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.6.1.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Any idea why it is happening? Thanks

It may due to that the project does not properly reference or cannot find the specified version of the assembly. Based on the information you've provided, here are a few suggestions:

Clean and rebuild the solution.
Your project references version 5.2.0 of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, but is looking for version 5.0.0.0. This may be due to some dependencies requiring version 5.0.0.0 of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient. You can try downgrading the version of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to 5.0.0.0, or find and update dependencies that require version 5.0.0.0.
Make sure that the specific version of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient (5.2.0) exists in your project's output directory. You can check the output directory to see if there is a Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll file.
Consider whether to obtain the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient from NuGet or manually add the correct assembly to the project instead of relying on HintPath.



Clean and rebuid. I actually created a new solution / project and just copied the c# code to it. It still doing the same.
v 5.0.0.0 has vulnerabilities. That said, I tried that too, and am getting the same error
See attached file I did copied Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to output folder.
I did get it from NuGet.
It is driving me nuts. I tried targeting .Net Framework. I tried System.Data.SqlClient and getting the same issue.
Any other ideas? Thanks


Here is the error after removing and re adding Microsoft.Data.SqlClinent
System.TypeInitializationException
  HResult=0x80131534
  Message=The type initializer for ... threw an exception.
  Source=AchieveResource
  StackTrace:
   at ....ConnectionStrings.GetEnterpriseConnectionString() in ...ConnectionStrings.cs:line 225
Inner Exception 1:
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5'. The system cannot find the file specified.


I think I know what is going on. In one of the steps I was catching errors without throwing them up. The error was Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform. On Microsoft site, it was not clear if Microsoft.Data.SqlClinet 5,2,8 compatible with 8.0. On the front page it shows .net 6 but somewhere else it showed .Net 8. Since then, I was trying changing the target of the project to match, but that did not work. Do you know what combination that does not have vulnerabilities of frame work and the tool will work? Thanks

Regarding this question you raised: Do you know what combination that does not have vulnerabilities of frame work and the tool will work? You can refer to Supportability in this link: https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient#supportability
In addition, I know from the Nuget package configuration in VS that the 5.2.0 version of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient depends on the .NET version has these: .NET 8.0, . NET6.0, .NET Framework 4.6.2, . NETStandard 2.0, 2.1.

I tried many combinations. For example, downgrading the project to .NET6,0. Nothing worked. Do you have a project combination that works with 5.2.0?
I don't know what else to do.
It all started after trying to user vs 2022 and .NET8. The same class libraries work perfectly with VS 2019 and Framework 4.81

Regarding the project combination applicable to 5.2.0, you can right-click your project in VS, select Manage Nuget Packages, and search for Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to view the corresponding dependencies.
